# Is it possible to do a result_scan in snowflake with the query nested

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The standard flow to query the result of a query looks like this.

[doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html)

```
describe table your_db.your_schema.your_table_name;

select 
    "name"
    ,"type"
    ,*
from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) ;
```

Ideally, you should be able to

```
select  
    "name"
    ,"type"
    ,*
from table(result_scan(describe table your_db.your_schema.your_table_name)) ;
```

Is something like this possible in reality or must I keep dreaming?

Comment: What's the general goal of this? At least the queries in the example wouldn't do much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for the following reasons

1. The doc clearly states that the RESULT_SCAN function only accept a query ID as an input argument.
2. RESULT_SCAN function scans the result of a **previously executed query**. Therefore that query must have occurred as a different transaction in the past

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth adding to Clark's answer that it's not presently possible, because presently the `DESCRIBE TABLE` is not run on the COMPUTE layer, but only of the SHARED SERVICES layer (meta data, query planner, etc).

*Originally back in my day*, there wasn't even a RESULTS_SCAN, and everything was externally parsed. So the RESULT_SCAN allows you to run a COMPUTE layer against the a prior result set, and thus we have a two step process. Now compared to other DB's where everything is a full DB object, thus everything is accessible via SQL this is frustrating.

But I feel when you know how/why it's the way it is, the steps make sense, and like many things once you get a "working pattern" you just do it. Albeit, at first it is different, and now how one might like it to be.